# WARNING in Invalid font values at 15949:4. Ignoring: Angular4 prod build

Tags: css, angular, fonts, angular-cli

Angular application style.css have imported Roboto font css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200,300,700');
```

This is working fine in development build but for ng build --prod,

It gives an error and font not loading on browser:

> WARNING in Invalid font values at 15949:4.

```
Nodejs: 6.11.4
Npm: 3.10.10
@angular/cli: 1.6.8
 "@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.0",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar issue happened to one of my project about Material design icons font.

Here is what I did to solve the similar issue I was facing.

1. Added `--verbose` parameter while building angular package.

   `ng build --prod --verbose`
2. In the details that appeared after executing above command gave me following details :

   `Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??extracted!src/styles.css:
   Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
   chunk    {0} * (mini-css-extract-plugin) 10.8 KiB [entry] [rendered]`

   `WARNING in Invalid font values at 1439:706. Ignoring.`
3. Above details specified a filename `src/styles.css` which I have modified during development. So I commented all the codes in that file and run the build command again. And IT WORKED!!!!.
4. Now that I know the problem is somewhere in `styles.css`, so I started moving few lines of code from inside comments to outside of it, then run the command again and see if warning appears.

   After repeating these 2 steps for more than 20 times, the warning `WARNING in Invalid font values` appeared. Thats how I came to know that following code was causing the issue

   `.mdi:before, .mdi-set { transition: all 0.2s; }`

   So I removed above code and Uncommented all the rest of the code in the same file `styles.css`. Now that warning `WARNING in Invalid font values` does not appear and angular builds the package perfectly.

Comment: in my case: ```transition: opacity background .15s ease-out;``` removed the word ```opacity```, as I found similar style rule in different file: ```transition: background .3s ease-in-out;```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to determine which file had the problem from the output, even with the verbose setting. It listed all of the CSS & SCSS files included in the project together, then all of the warnings at the end. There was nothing I could see that associated specific warnings to specific files.

What I ended up doing was to remove all of the entries from the `"styles"` property for the `"build"` action in angular.json. I then added them back one at a time and rebuild the app with `ng build --prod`. Once the warnings appeared, then I knew it was the last file I added back that had the problem. Then I looked in that file for the property from the warning message (it was `background` for me, but would be `font` in the OP's case), until I found one that had an invalid value, and changed it to a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

refer here for possible solutions to similar problem: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9648

ran "ng build --target=production --environment=prod --aot=false" and was able to get a build without warnings when i ran into a similar problem

Comment: Error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Spent lots of hour debugging this and finally came to realize my problem. In my case was the `font` property in the `styles.scss` file, I was using it with a variable, like `font: 10px $font-regular`. I dont know why this is "wrong" but when I change/split it to multiple properties, the `WARNING` dissapear. Like this:

```
{
  font-family: $font-regular;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
}
```